# How to populate related list records in VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lookup

I Need to populate the related records(from Custom objects) or contact associated with the Account like multipicklist view in Vf page so the user selects the related records from the list.On a button click the records should get saved

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit?  Are you trying to display the related list on a visualforce page, or are you trying to update the parent object's related list records from an action in your controller / vf page?

Answer (score 1):

we use for similar purposes a custom component, which looks like multi select picklist. This link will be useful for you: [multiselect picklist](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/06/a-multiselect-picklist-visualforce-component.html).